# Find the Position of a Character of a Subsequence in a String and Return in List

Tags: python

Is there a general outline of a function that can be used to find the position of a character of a subsequence in a string and returns the position in a list?

To be a little more specific, for example, your subsequence is “ABC” and your string is “ADFBEIC”. How would return the position for each character/letter of the subsequence in the string and return the positions in a list?

Answer (score 0):

Tell me if this is what you are looking for

**For a better understanding of what it does**

It basically iterates through `subsequence`.
For every letter in subsequence, it will check where you can find it in `string`. If it is found, it will append the index to `indexes`

```
subsequence = "ABC"
string = "ADFBEIC"
indexes = [string.index(i) for i in subsequence]
print(indexes)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
subsequence = 'ABC'
string='ADFBEIC'

for i in string:
    if i in subsequence:
        print(string.index(i))
```